# How can i fetch Push Notification settings in my app?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I am developing an iphone application which includes and process apple push notification for the custom sound file. When I set notification sound off from the general settings, notification sound is off as i expect, when app is not in running state. But when the app is in running state then i need to handle sound play or stop manually. So how can i fetch the notification sound related settings, whether it seted on or off? 
I am able to fetch following settings in **didReceiveRemoteNotification**
method

**alert = New UFO Information received, badge = 1, sound = Alarm1.wav**

If anybody have any idea about to fetch general settings like alert sound is on or off please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
       if ([application enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] & UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) {
         AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0x3f4);
         AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

First check your app staust and open push notification setting with this code.

**For iOS 5 and later vesion.**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID"]];
```

For open any setting of iphone app check this link.

http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/open-settings-app-in-iphone-using-open-url-scheme/